# How long does it take to get the renunciation letter from Bangladesh?

Tags: visas, passports, embassies, bangladeshi-citizens, bangladesh

How long does it take for Bangladesh to send the renunciation letter? I'm waiting for my renunciation letter from the Bangladesh embassy before applying for a Sri Lankan passport. I surrendered the Bangladesh passport. It has been 5 months since I surrendered my passport to the Bangladesh embassy. The Sri Lanka-Bangladesh embassy in Colombo has not responded. When I ask them how long it will take, they say they don't know. I'm not even a citizen of any country.

Comment: According to https://www.bangladeshembassy.de/requirements-for-renunciation-of-bangladesh-nationality/ to get final renunciation certificate approval from the Ministry of Home Affairs, Dhaka, Bangladesh  is required and it takes around 06 (six) months to 02 (two) years.

Comment: I saw this. How practical it is to stay without a passport for 2 years if it is actually going to take 2 years.

Comment: Certainly up to two years seems a long time to wait, whether that’s practical depends on circumstances eg if you need your passport for other official purposes. Is it 100% mandatory for a foreign national to renounce their (presumably) birth nationality *before* applying for Sri Lankan citizenship? Have you sought advice from an immigration lawyer?

Comment: @NimanthaDeshappriya : Have you got any response from Bangladesh consulate. I also apply for renunciation , so wonder how your current situation